# Can not connect visual studio code to PHP

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code, xampp

I'm just beginning at PhP and VS Code. I tried using `"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/Program Files/php-8.0.0/php.exe"` in settings.json but it didn't work (This is my path to PhP). Then I looked up on youtube and they said if im using XAMPP (which I am) to download in libraries "open in browser addon for PHP/JS/...)- that also didnt solve here is what it looks in my settings.json

```
"open-php-html-js-in-browser.selectedBrowser": "Chrome",
    "open-php-html-js-in-browser.customUrlToOpen": "http://127.0.0.1/${relativeDirnameDocumentRoot}/${fileBasename}"
```

Whenever I try to open to index.php in browser with apache this displays:
[image]

I hit a road block and I don't know how to proceede with this, if anyone knows how to solve this please help. Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found my answer, you need to add folder to xammp folder of your choice. For instance you will add test file where you will copy all your html files and you transfer them to PhP files.